# Что такое перцентиль, как с ним работать и как его вычислять?

Tags: математика, терминология

Объясните, что такое перцинтель? Как он вычисляется? Какая у него формула для вычисления, если она существует.

Например дан набор таких данных:

1
3
5
7
9

Как вычислить 99 процентиль? 90ый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения процентиля **p** данные нужно разделить так, чтобы слева находилось p% данных, справа (100-p)%  данных, а разделительный элемент (самый правый из левой части) был больше (или равен) всех левых, и меньше (или равен) всех правых.

В частности, этого можно достичь сортировкой данных и получением элемента с индексом `p * N / 100`  (сортировка несколько избыточна для данного действия, но если данные уже сортированы - остальное просто).

Например, медиана (процентиль 50) есть элемент, который больше половины элементов, и меньше другой половины. Для приведённого набора медиана  - 5.

Квартиль - больше четверти элементов. Второй квартиль совпадает с медианой, а в более широком смысле так может называться часть набора данных от первого квартиля до медианы и т.д.

Длина приведённого в вопросе набора слишком мала, поэтому указанные процентили будут на самом большом элементе.

Answer (score 0):

> **Перцентиль** - это показатель, используемый в статистике, показывающий значение, ниже которого падает определенный процент
>   наблюдений в группе наблюдений

**Пример расчёта**

```
Процентиль = n(x≤X)/N*100
```

[image: Percentile]

Если мало, вот тебе ссылка на [**wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) там всё подробно расписано